# Связь между загрузчиком и отображением

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Пытаюсь сделать загрузчик ( пишу его на листочках ), но у меня проблема со связью его ( загрузчика ) с вью. Связь нужно чтобы выводить прогресс загрузки и сообщения об ошибках.
Подскажите, как более правильно реализовать такую связь.

Да, приложение строится на MVС. А как должно быть?
Тут ещё вот какое дело - сейчас я уточняю, как наладить связь между вью и загрузчиком, при первом старте. То есть, выполнился Main и создал класс конфигурации приложения, где и создаются модель, вью, контроллер и получают настройки менеджеры. В один из этих менеджеров входит и ассет менеджер, в задачу которого входит создавать загрузчики и забирая контент, складывать его в фабрики. И получается, что если сначала запустить загрузку, то вью не сможет отображать прогресс.

И ещё вот какой момент я не понимаю. Есть задача в запущенном приложении, грузить фото.
 Запускается сценарий загрузки и ассет менеджер создает столько загрузчиков, скольно нужно загрузить фото. От сюда вопрос - как вью получить ссылки на все эти загрузчики, чтобы для каждого создать вью-прогресса загрузки?

У меня ещё просьба - решил в образовательных целях посмотреть, как в RL2 сделано, но второй день сижу в недоумении.. Не получается запустить.. Посмотрите пожалуйста, что у меня не так?
    package 
    {
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;

```
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            new MainContext(this);
        }
    }

}

package  
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import robotlegs.bender.bundles.mvcs.MVCSBundle;
    import robotlegs.bender.extensions.contextView.ContextView;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IContext;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.impl.Context;

    public class MainContext 
    {
        private var _context:IContext;

        public function MainContext(viewPort:DisplayObjectContainer) 
        {
            this.startup(viewPort);
        }

        private function startup(viewPort:DisplayObjectContainer):void
        {
            _context = new Context().install(MVCSBundle).
            configure(MainConfiguration, new ContextView(viewPort));
        }

    }

}

package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import robotlegs.bender.extensions.contextView.ContextView;
    import robotlegs.bender.extensions.eventCommandMap.api.IEventCommandMap;
    import robotlegs.bender.extensions.mediatorMap.api.IMediatorMap;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IConfig;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IInjector;

    public class MainConfiguration implements IConfig
    {
        [Inject]
        protected var inject:IInjector;

        [Inject]
        protected var mediatorMap:IMediatorMap;

        [Inject]
        protected var commandMap:IEventCommandMap;

        [Inject]
        protected var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;

        [Inject]
        protected var context:ContextView;

        public function configure():void
        {
            commandMap.map(Event.CHANGE, Event).toCommand(PreloderViewProgressCommand);// здесь выдает ошибку 1009

            dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));

        }
    }

}

    package  
{
    public class PreloderViewProgressCommand 
    {
        public function execute():void 
        {
            trace("[PreloderViewProgressCommand] - method execute");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Самый простой способ: паттерн Синглтон
* у класса загрузчика есть статическое поле instance, которое содержит ссылку на экземпляр загрузчика
* во вью слушаем сообщения загрузчика


    Loader.instance.addEventListener( Event.PROGRESS, prHandler );

или ловим ошибку

    Loader.instance.addEventListener( Event.ERROR, errHandler );

Comment: Если приложение строится на MVC принципах, то синглтон должен быть реализован по другому. Данное решение будет не совсем правильное.

Comment: Да, приложение строится на MVС. А как должно быть?
### дописал на верху.

Comment: А какая реалиация mvc? RobotLegs, PureMVC?

Comment: Я не пользуюсь фраймворками. я только учусь и решил их пока не трогать, хотя, я изучал их оба ( в большей степени RL2 ) и многое из них подчерпнул.

Comment: Выношу в полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ: паттерн Синглтон - у класса загрузчика есть статическое поле instance, которое содержит ссылку на экземпляр загрузчика, во вью слушаем сообщения загрузчика.

```
Loader.instance.addEventListener( Event.PROGRESS, prHandler );
```

или ловим ошибку

```
Loader.instance.addEventListener( Event.ERROR, errHandler );
```

Относительно схемы MVC (на примере robotlegs)

- 1-й способ) - Пускаем все нужные события (прогресс, ошибки) из загрузчика в контекст, (лучше бы это делала модель ассетов после валидации загруженного контента), из контекста эти события вылавливает медиатор вида, и проводит отображение этих операций в вид.
- 2-й способ) - Загрузчик оформлен как сервис и инжектирован (DI) в медиатор вида, медиатор после готовности вида запускает старт загрузки, ловит её события и отображает в вид.
- 3-й способ) - Конфигуратор приложения генерирует цепочку событий-команд (контроллеров) для старта загрузчика и отображения вида, внутри команд отрабатываются все события загрузки и отображения.

Последний способ самый сложный, но и более правильный по парадигме robotlegs.

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо! А не могли бы Вы дать ссылку на пример или ещё как-то объяснить третий пункт?

Comment: /* INTERFACE robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IConfig */
    public function configure():void 
    {
    // Commands triggers.
    commandMap.map( PreloaderEvent.LOADER_READY, PreloaderEvent ).toCommand( PreloaderViewStartupCommand );
    commandMap.map( PreloaderEvent.PROGRESS, PreloaderEvent ).toCommand( PreloaderViewProgressCommand );
    commandMap.map( PreloaderEvent.ERROR, PreloaderEvent ).toCommand( PreloaderViewErrorCommand );
    }

Comment: Напомню: нужна промежуточная модель/сервис/событие который сообщать в медиатор от этих команд, так как в командах нельзя использовать ссылку на view

пс: я б на вашем месте использовал второй вариант, третий для тяжелых приложений, с сотнями классов